# Create several columns with default values in Salesforce

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like 1000 rows, 10 columns

I want to add 20 columns with only one single value in each column (what I call a default value)

Therefore, my final df would be 1000 rows, with 30 columns

I know that I can do it 30 times by doing:

```
df['column 11'] = 'default value'
df['column 12'] = 'default value 2'
```

But I would like to do it in a proper way of coding

I have a dict with my `{'column label' : 'defaultvalues'}`

How can I do so ?

I've tried `pd.insert` or `pd.concatenate` but couldn't find my way through

thanks

regards,

Eric

Comment: `df.assign(**some_dict_mapping_label_to_value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if possible spaces in keys in dictionary for new columns names use `DataFrame` constuctor with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(5)})
print (df)
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

d = {'A 11' : 's', 'A 12':'c'}
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(d, index=df.index))
print (df)
   a A 11 A 12
0  0    s    c
1  1    s    c
2  2    s    c
3  3    s    c
4  4    s    c
```

If no spaces and no numbers in columns names (need valid identifier) is possible use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
d = {'A11' : 's', 'A12':'c'}
df = df.assign(**d)
print (df)
   a A11 A12
0  0   s   c
1  1   s   c
2  2   s   c
3  3   s   c
4  4   s   c
```

---

Another solution is loop by dictionary and assign:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    df[k] = v
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do so:

```
df_len = len(df)
new_df = pd.DataFrame({col: [val] * df_len for col,val in your_dict.items()})
df = pd.concat((df,new_df), axis=1)
```